# How can i search places with specific type

Tags: api, foursquare

I am using Foursquare API to get the nearest locations for my current location. Can anyone please guide me how I can get the nearest places of a specific type? (I mean I need all gas stations, cafes, etc. near me).

Here is the link I am using `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=41.104805,29.024291&oauth_token=EDO2GW34NJ5QBUVL5YXQTDYK41X2QMFBHS1XCY1FZMJFWNVM&v=20111229`

Here I get some locations but I am unable to find gas stations or cafes so please guide me how can I get those specific places near by me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The search parameter documentation is here:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

You can make an API call to get the categories.  The doc is here:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories

The actual call is:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories

And it returns all the categories - you need to parse through this json return object to find what you're looking for.

Once you've got your category (in this case let's use Gas Stations), you can add category to the query you already had:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?**categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d113951735**&ll=41.104805,29.024291&oauth_token=EDO2GW34NJ5QBUVL5YXQTDYK41X2QMFBHS1XCY1FZMJFWNVM&v=20111229

Comment: yes...thanks for your response ..how can get two categories at a time i mean i need gas_station as well as cafes so any idea about this

Comment: you can only search one category at a time, so you'll need to make two separate requests to get 'gas stations' and 'cafes'

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to OAUTH for venue searches which is great since you don't need to have people log into the system unless they want to check-in. Some do and some don't

Simply use:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll="+ ll+"&intent=browse&radius=10000&limit=75&categoryId="+catID+"&client_secret=xxx&client_id=xxxx
```

As far as I know, but never tried - but the api says you can combine categories in a comma delimted list, say `catID = xxxxx,yyyyyy,zzzzz`

By browsing, ie `intent=browse` you can set the location and radius more specifically, say you want to see San Fancisco, due to being there tonight from your home in Atlanta...Without browse, you are simply searching "Nearby". I have not tried this yet, but know I can expand my current location's radius.

I do not like the OAUTH welcome web address. Gets me where I do not want if someone clicks the link in OAUTH.